# ListViewItem generating "The given key was not present in the dictionary." error

Tags: listviewitem

How can

```
ItemCheckedEventArgs.Item.Selected = ItemCheckedEventArgs.Item.Checked
```

generate "The given key was not present in the dictionary." ??

Comment: Can I add a psychic-debugging tag?  A little more context would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion was due to the fact that VS does not step into event handlers when you step through properties, so I wasn't seeing the error in my SelectedIndexChanged handler.